# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkproj4

Tags: compiling, make

I am trying to compile [some provided code](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/range_image_visualization.php#range-image-visualization) I found online by executing make. But when I do so it returns "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkproj4"

```
-ThinkPad-X200:~/PCL/visualRangeExample/build$ make
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable range_image_visualization
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkproj4
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/build.make:364: recipe for target 'range_image_visualization' failed
make[2]: *** [range_image_visualization] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried to install vtkproj4 and vtkproj4-dev but those packages dont seem to exsist (and none of their variants), in order to get rid of this error.

I am following a video tutorial and [this is the exact moment where I am stuck](https://youtu.be/CXK95Hi4M7I?t=243).

What else can I do to solve this issue?

Thanks

**EDIT:** There has already been a bugreport 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vtk6/+bug/1573234

But that didn't help me as they tell the bug will be fixed for ubuntu >= 16.10 while I am on 16.04

This is the Makefile generated by cmake

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.5

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all

.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:


#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:


# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list


# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:


# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:

.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/bin/cmake -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /home/yalishanda/PCL/visualRangeExample

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /home/yalishanda/PCL/visualRangeExample/build

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "No interactive CMake dialog available..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -E echo No\ interactive\ CMake\ dialog\ available.
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache

.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache

.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/yalishanda/PCL/visualRangeExample/build/CMakeFiles /home/yalishanda/PCL/visualRangeExample/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/yalishanda/PCL/visualRangeExample/build/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean

.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named range_image_visualization

# Build rule for target.
range_image_visualization: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 range_image_visualization
.PHONY : range_image_visualization

# fast build rule for target.
range_image_visualization/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/build
.PHONY : range_image_visualization/fast

range_image_visualization.o: range_image_visualization.cpp.o

.PHONY : range_image_visualization.o

# target to build an object file
range_image_visualization.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/range_image_visualization.cpp.o
.PHONY : range_image_visualization.cpp.o

range_image_visualization.i: range_image_visualization.cpp.i

.PHONY : range_image_visualization.i

# target to preprocess a source file
range_image_visualization.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/range_image_visualization.cpp.i
.PHONY : range_image_visualization.cpp.i

range_image_visualization.s: range_image_visualization.cpp.s

.PHONY : range_image_visualization.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
range_image_visualization.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/range_image_visualization.dir/range_image_visualization.cpp.s
.PHONY : range_image_visualization.cpp.s

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... range_image_visualization"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... range_image_visualization.o"
    @echo "... range_image_visualization.i"
    @echo "... range_image_visualization.s"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

**EDIT 2:**

I tried installing libvtk and those were the results:

```
yalishanda@yalishanda-ThinkPad-X200:~/PCL/visualRangeExample/build$ sudo apt install libvtk
[sudo] password for yalishanda: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libvtk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libvtk5.10:i386 libvtk5.10

E: Package 'libvtk' has no installation candidate


sudo apt install libvtk5.10

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libvtk5.10 is already the newest version (5.10.1+dfsg-2.1build1).
libvtk5.10 set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gimp-data gimp-help-common gimp-help-en libamd2.4.1 libbabl-0.1-0 libbtf1.2.1 libcamd2.4.1 libccolamd2.9.1 libcsparse3.1.4 libcxsparse3.1.4
  libgimp2.0 libklu1.3.3 libldl2.2.1 linux-headers-4.8.0-36 linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-36-generic snap-confine
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Please add your `Makefile` to the question.

Comment: @heemayl updated my post